# video in webview should display full screen on onShowCustomView() method in android

Tags: android, video, webview, android-webview

i want to display video full screen (that is full screen horizontally) landscape..
when onShowCustomView() method is called ,

what is happening in my case is that video is display in same orientation in which onShowCustomView() method is called ... that is is screen is in portrait and onShowCustomView() is called video is displayed vertically full screen , i want it should be displayed horizontally fullscreen

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main26Activity extends Activity {
private WebView view6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main26);



    String url6 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPK43O87atA";
    view6=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView6);
    view6.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view6.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view6.setWebViewClient(new Browser());
    view6.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebClient());
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        view6.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else
    {
        view6.loadUrl(url6);
    }

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "please wait while episodes are loaded";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
public void onPause()
{
    view6.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
class Browser
        extends WebViewClient
{
    Browser() {}

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView paramWebView, String paramString)
    {
        paramWebView.loadUrl(paramString);
        return true;
    }
}

public class MyWebClient
        extends WebChromeClient
{
    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    public MyWebClient() {}

    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
    {
        if (Main26Activity.this == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Main26Activity.this.getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
    }

    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)Main26Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        Main26Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        Main26Activity.this.setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = Main26Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = Main26Activity.this.getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)Main26Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        Main26Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    view6.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    view6.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (view6.canGoBack()) {
        view6.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I just faced your problem and I deal with it in another way.

Actually, the view returned by onShowCustomView is a VideoView or its father. It stands vertical because your device orientation is portrait. So we can do something on the fullscreen view's container. Just make a "landscape" layout as your container.

Here is my simple code:

```
public class LandscapeFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public LandscapeFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        //Attention: The arithmetic below is based on padding == 0.
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child != null) {
                child.setRotation(90);
                int width = right - left;
                int height = bottom - top;
                child.setTranslationX((width - height) / 2);
                child.setTranslationY((height - width) / 2);
            }
        }
        super.onLayout(changed, 0, 0, bottom, right);
    }
}
```

What the code above do is rotate its children by 90 degree and adjust there position.