# Using an Android Webview, how do I pass control of the MediaPlayer to the Activity

Tags: android, android-webview, android-mediaplayer

I have an app where the activity loads a webview that has video playing on it.

My ultimate goal is to play media in the background from the webview, pretty much exactly as Chrome does it right now.

Here is a screenshot of chrome running this logic when the device is unlocked:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of the same video playing when the device is locked:
[image]

I have already set my webview with a custom `ChromeClient` that has overridden the MediaPlayer methods I need.

```
public class MyCustomChromeClient extends WebChromeClient implements
            MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{

        private MediaPlayer mp;

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (this.mp != null) {
                this.mp.release();
            } else {
                mp.release();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            this.mp = mp;
            //Utilizing this MediaPlayer Here
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            //Handle Error stuff here 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have followed multiple tutorials on the subject and while I have most of the logic in place, I cannot figure out how to actually *take control* of the media player so as to intercept it from Chrome and have my code take over the play, pause, and stop functionalities.

Here is some of the reference material I have been using:

1. https://shashikawlp.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/play-html5-video-on-android-webview/
2. [video in webview should display full screen on onShowCustomView() method in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300770/video-in-webview-should-display-full-screen-on-onshowcustomview-method-in-andr)
3. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030
4. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-mediasession-part-3-4-b4919583a82
5. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/media-apps-overview
6. https://www.nigeapptuts.com/android-media-viewer-mediaplayer-mediasessioncompat/
7. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-a-simple-audio-app-in-android-part-1-3-c14d1a66e0f1

Pretty much all of them address how to do most of what I want, but the core issue of intercepting the MediaPlayer and preventing it from playing or pausing except via my forwarded commands is not one of them.

**How do I go about recreating Chrome's background media player option for my own webview, or, barring the possibility of that, can I interact with Chrome's built-in one via some interface?**

**Update:**
So it appears that viewing the same page on a regular chrome browser actually **does** what I want it to; it plays the video / audio and allows it to continue in the background. So the next logical follow-up question is, what on earth did I do in my Webview that is causing this to work on a native chrome browser, but not my app? Is there something I could have overridden that would do this?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: I did not. Ended up writing the entire thing from scratch using a service framework and bindings after abandoning this approach. If you have any luck on your end, please let me know!

Comment: I've unfortunately also ended up writing it on my own. Too bad Google supports this in Chrome, but not in WebView...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is very probably that the page will be using the 'MediaSession' API, and this is supported in Chrome but [not in WebView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession#browser_compatibility).

In terms of what you can do about it, you could write a 'Javascript bridge' component to send page events back to the WebView, and in doing so, replicate the MediaSession interactions. This would be easier if you owned the page in question, but you might still be able to locate and query audio/video elements in any page. Either way, the detail of this is too complex to try and describe here.

Comment: Do you have an example for this?